# How to deny rows deletion based on class property value? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to deny deletion of a row in case some there is a property with specific value, for example if product type is Steel I would like to deny user from deleting that row..

I'm setting source to my datagrid like this:

```
dataGridSourceList = new ObservableCollection<DatabaseItems>(TempController.Instance.SelectItemsByUserId(Globals.CurrentUser.Id));
dtgMainItems.ItemsSource = dataGridSourceList;
```

I saw there is a property `CanUserDeleteRows`

And I've added this to definition of my datagrid in xaml but I'm not sure how to apply this properly..

```
CanUserDeleteRows="{Binding ElementName=dtgMainItems, Path=SelectedItem.IsDeleteEnabled}"
```

Any kind of help would be awesome
Thanks

Comment: You code is correct, it looks for `DatabaseItems.IsDeleteEnables` property, so just add it there.

Comment: @icebat how do you mean? could you provide an answer with that sample?

Comment: Is having a button out of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `CommandManager.PreviewCanExecute` attached event:

```
private void OnPreviewCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == DataGrid.DeleteCommand)
    {
        DatabaseItems selectedItem = dtgMainItems.SelectedItem as DatabaseItems;
        if (selectedItem != null && !selectedItem.IsDeleteEnabled)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgMainItems" CommandManager.PreviewCanExecute="Grid_PreviewCanExecute" />
```

Comment: Thanks mate for your great help